# What is the best practice for starting a new thread when using Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I'm following along this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components_20.html) for using Android Architecture Components with Firebase Realtime Database. Currently, I am at the part of the blog where I move the `LiveData` callbacks to `onChanged()` onto a different thread.

This is what I have (the Kotlin equivalent of the Java code from the blog):

```
private val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid
private val USERS_REF: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")
private val liveData: FirebaseQueryLiveData = FirebaseQueryLiveData(USERS_REF)
private val usersLiveData: MediatorLiveData<Users> = MediatorLiveData()

fun UsersViewModel() {
    usersLiveData.addSource(liveData, object : Observer<DataSnapshot> {
        override fun onChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                Thread(Runnable() {
                    run() {
                        usersLiveData.postValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(Users::class.java))
                    }
                }).start()
            } else {
                usersLiveData.value = null
            }
        }
    })
}
```

In the blog, it states that the way it has shown to start up a new thread is not considered the "best practice" for starting another thread in a production app. The suggestion is to use an `Executor` with a pool of reusable threads for a job like this.

How do I modify the current Runnable Thread so that it uses an optimal practice for starting a new thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a new thread at all here.  Just remove it.

`postValue()` is asynchronous and doesn't block anything.  You can call it safely on the main thread.  Any LiveData observers will get the value immediately after the database callback completes.